# import superjson in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am building a react native app with expo. I want to use `superjson` to encode and decode data for `async-storage` but when I import it, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve "superjson" from "path/to/my-file.ts"

I downloaded it via `yarn`:

> yarn add superjson

and I imported like this:

```js
import SuperJSON from "superjson"
```

**EDIT:**

it works when import it like this:

```js
import SuperJSON from "superjson/dist/index"
```

but I still don't understand why it doesn't work without `/dist/index` and how can I fix it

Comment: There is no main file in the package.json  of the superjson 
you can test it by adding   "main":"./dist/index.js", in the package.json
difficulty?  there is no difficulty!